# Playwright how to wait till website reloads?

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

My current code logs me in on buff.163. The only problem is that before the page reloads and logs me in there is a around 3 seconds delay. I already tried `page.wait_for_load_state("load")` but it doesnt work. I think its of the 3 second delay.

Comment: Can you describe why `page.wait_for_load_state("load")` doesn't work? Can you not find elements after the load function is executed? Also, you don't need to put the argument "load" in, it defaults to "load", replace it with this: `page.wait_for_load_state()`.